# if you are in safety zone and you get a backwards 4, do you move backwards and then forwards?

Tags: sorry

if you are in safety zone and you get a backwards 4, do you move backwards and then forwards?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are asking... it sounds like a duplicate of the linked question; but if you are asking something different, please clarify. Do you mean move backwards now, and on a later turn move forwards again?